# Inherit Hover state in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Its a pretty simple scenario but i can't find an in-framework solution.
I have a link with text and an icon. On hover of the link the icon should get another color than the linktext.

```
<a href="#" class="block text-black hover:text-red"><i class="fa fa-icon text-grey hover:text-blue"></i>
```

The icon hover only triggers when the mouse is over it not the link as a whole.
I know i can still write custom classes in tailwind but this is such a basic problem that I hope someone knows a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `group` class to link and use `group-hover:` on the icon.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<a href="#" class="block p-6 border group text-black hover:text-red">
  <span class="text-grey group-hover:text-blue-500">icon</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats it. I looked for inherit in the docs and found nothing, I should have scrolled the hover: doc all way down instead hehe.